# Bind property to the Run in a Textblock?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can I bind a property to the Run tag in a Textblock control in WPF. And I am using MVVM.

Comment: Do you mean you want to bind to the Text Property of a Run?

Comment: Yes. but I have to add that run to Textblock.

Answer (score 1):

you did not post some code, but this works

```
<Grid>
  <TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Path=MyViewmodelProperty}"/>
  </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET 4.0, you can bind to the Text property of a Run. Before that, it's not possible. Can't you just bind to the TextBlock.Text property?